# Google Cloud translate JSON file

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-cloud-platform

I would like to translate the fields of a composite JSON object using Google Cloud Platform, instead of translating every single sentence on its own. Is it possible?

Example (from English to Italian):

Origin JSON file:

```
{job_description: {
    name: "Taxi driver",
    description: "like the movie"
    }
}
```

Output JSON file:

```
{job_description: {
    name: "Tassista",
    description: "Come nel film"
    }
}
```

Comment: You could look into https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate. "attranslate" is a simple tool for translating JSON-files, and it also supports Google Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation API accepts only plain-text or HTML as a format [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate).

To achieve your goal, load your JSON file as an object in your code, send the fields to the Translation API, edit the object with the translation result and then generate a JSON file from your new object.

Comment: So basically appending them as "q" parameters to the api endpoint url? It makes sense as a solution. Still hope it could be implemented one day. Thanks for your contribute.

Comment: If you are using API yes, you can also have look at [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library)

Comment: Google translates keys when JSON being sent

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script I wrote to achieve this. Hope this helps someone.
https://github.com/EisenVault/json-google-translate

Answer (score -4):

{
"meta": {
"language": "German",
"language_locale": "Deutsch",
"author": "Maskabor ([www.kvor.net](http://www.kvor.net))",
"gameversion": "1.0"
},
"stats": {
"ammoCost": "Munitionskosten",
"battleTier": "Gefechtsstufe",
"battles": "Gefechte",
"battlesInVehicle": "Gefechte im Panzer",
"battlesWon": "Gefechte gewonnen",
"bonds": "Anleihen",
"bondsCost": "Anleihen ausgeg.",
"bondsIncome": "Anleihen erhalten",
"bondsNett": "Anleihen Gewinn",
"bondsSpent": "Anleihen ausgeg.", # Shortened
"capturePoints": "Eroberungspunkte",
"classicBattles": "Gefechte:",
"classicDef": "Abgewehrt:",
"classicDmg": "Schaden:",
"classicEconomy": "Gesamt",
"classicGold": "Gold",
"classicKills": "Abschüsse:",
"classicLabelAvg": "Durchschnitt:",
"classicLabelTotal": "Gesamt:",
"classicLabelXpc": "XPC:",
"classicSpot": "Aufgeklärt:",
"classicTier": "Stufe",
"classicWN8": "WN8:",
"classicXP": "Erfahrung:",
"consumableCost": "Ausrüstung Kosten",
"creditsGross": "Kredit erhalten",
"creditsNett": "Kredit Gewinn",
"creditsSpent": "Kredit ausgegeben",
"crewXP": "Besatzung Erfahr.", # Shortened
"damage": "Schaden",
"damageAssisted": "Unterstütz. schaden", # Shortened
"damageSniper": "Schaden über 300m",
"damageSpot": "Schaden aufgeklärt",
"damageTrack": "Schaden fahrwerk", # Changed
"defencePoints": "Verteidigungspunkte",
"freeXP": "Freie Erfahrung",
"goldGross": "Gold erhalten",
"goldNett": "Gold Gewinn",
"goldSpent": "Gold ausgegeben",
"kills": "Abschüsse",
"moe": "Erfolgsmark. Wert",
"moeChange": "Erfolgsmark. Änder.", # Shortened
"moeChangeFirst": "Erfolgsmark. Wert", # Shortened
"moeChangeLast": "Erfolgsmark. Wert", # Shortened
"moeDamage": "Erfolgsmark. Schaden", # Shortened
"moeDamageWithReq": "Erfolgsmark.", # Shortened
"moeDmgNeeded65": "1. Erfolgsmark.", # Shortened
"moeDmgNeeded85": "2. Erfolgsmark.", # Shortened
"moeDmgNeeded95": "3. Erfolgsmark.", # Shortened
"moeDmgNeededNextMark": "Nächste Erfolgsmark.", # Shortened
"originalXP": "Erfahrungspunkte",
"placeInTeam": "Platz im Team",
"potentialDamageReceived": "Pot. Schaden erhalten.", # Potentieller Schaden erhalten
"repairCost": "Reparaturkosten",
"shotsReceivedGold": "Premium Munition Treffer erhalten", # Too long
"shotsReceivedCredits": "Treffer erhalten Kreditpunkte", # Too long
"spot": "Aufgeklärt",
"survived": "Überlebt",
"tier": "Stufe",
"tier1Below": "Stufe - 1",
"tier2Below": "Stufe - 2",
"tierDiff1": "1. Stufe Unterschied",
"tierDiff2": "2. Stufe Unterschied",
"tierDiff3": "3. Stufe Unterschied",
"tierTop": "Top Stufe", # changed
"WN8": "WN8",
"wn8ExpectedDamage": "WN8 erwarteter Schaden",
"wn8ExpectedKills": "WN8 erwartete Abschüsse",
"xp": "Erfahrung"
},
"interface": {
"battleTypeEpic": "Großgefechte",
"battleTypeFrontline": "Frontlinie",
"battleTypeRandom": "Zufallsgefecht",
"battleTypeRanked": "Gewertet",
"battleTypeStrongholdMap": "Festung:Gefechte",
"battleTypeStrongholdSkirmishes": "Bollwerk",
"battleTypeTeamUnranked": "Team Gefecht",
"battleTypesShown": "Gefechtsart Anzeigen",
"buttonInfo": "Schaltfläche Zusatzinformation",
"buttonInfoBlank": "Nichts",
"buttonInfoClock": "Uhr",
"buttonInfoDefault": "Standard",
"buttonInfoWN8": "WN8",
"font": "Schriftart",
"fontSelect": "Schriftart wählen",
"fontSizeSelect": "Schriftgröße wählen",
"liveStatsDragText": "STRG drücken CTRL\nicht drücken",
"liveStatsMOE": "FTM",
"liveStatsWN8": "WN8",
"noBattlesPlayed": "Gefechte gespielt",
"reloadConfig": "Konfiguration laden",
"reset": "Zurücksetzen",
"restore": "Wiederherstellen",
"setup": "EINSTELLUNGEN",
"actual": "Aktuell",
"expected": "Erwartet",
"total": "Gesamt",
"average": "Durchschnitt",
"wn8SourceDistribution": "WN8 Quelle",
"tierPlacement": "Stufe",
"tierDifference": "Stufen Unterschied",
"wn8Expected": "WN8 erwartet",
"export": "Export",
"exportSelect": "Exportpfad: ",
"exportSavedTo": "Export gespeichert unter:",
"session": "Sitzung",
"buildInSessionStats": "Eingebaute Sitzungs-Statistik",
"buildInSessionStatsShow": "Zeigen",
"buildInSessionStatsHide": "Verbergen",
"language": "Sprache", # computer translated
"localesSelect": "Sprache auswählen" # computer translated
}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).