# Translate JSON file's specific field

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-translate

I would like to translate the field "text" from the [flight](https://github.com/google-research-datasets/Taskmaster/blob/master/TM-2-2020/data/flights.json) domain of the [Taskmaster-2](https://github.com/google-research-datasets/Taskmaster/blob/master/TM-2-2020/data/flights.json) dataset. Which is a deeply nested JSON file. Using Google Cloud Translate how can I do it?

Example (from English to Bangla):

Origin JSON file:

```
[ {
"conversation_id": "dlg-00100680-00e0-40fe-8321-6d81b21bfc4f",
"instruction_id": "flight-12",
"utterances": [
  {
    "index": 0,
    "speaker": "USER",
    "text": "Hello. I'd like to find a round trip commercial airline flight from San Francisco to Denver.",
    "segments": [
      {
        "start_index": 26,
        "end_index": 36,
        "text": "round trip",
        "annotations": [
          {
            "name": "flight_search.type"
          }
        ]
      },
```

Output JSON file:

```
[ {
"conversation_id": "dlg-00100680-00e0-40fe-8321-6d81b21bfc4f",
"instruction_id": "flight-12",
"utterances": [
  {
    "index": 0,
    "speaker": "USER",
    "text": "হ্যালো. আমি সান ফ্রান্সিসকো থেকে ডেনভার পর্যন্ত একটি রাউন্ড ট্রিপ বাণিজ্যিক এয়ারলাইন ফ্লাইট খুঁজতে চাই।",
    "segments": [
      {
        "start_index": 26,
        "end_index": 36,
        "text": "রাউন্ড ট্রিপ",
        "annotations": [
          {
            "name": "flight_search.type"
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: Refer This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363245/) Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extracted a few lines of data in [flights.json](https://github.com/google-research-datasets/Taskmaster/blob/master/TM-2-2020/data/flights.json) and used the code below written in Python using [Google Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translate-text-basic#translate_translate_text-python) to translate English to Japanese. Also see list of [supported languages](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages) of the API.

**test.json**:

```json
[
  {
    "conversation_id": "dlg-00100680-00e0-40fe-8321-6d81b21bfc4f",
    "instruction_id": "flight-12",
    "utterances": [
      {
        "index": 0,
        "speaker": "USER",
        "text": "Hello. I'd like to find a round trip commercial airline flight from San Francisco to Denver.",
        "segments": [
          {
            "start_index": 26,
            "end_index": 36,
            "text": "round trip",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "flight_search.type"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start_index": 68,
            "end_index": 81,
            "text": "San Francisco",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "flight_search.origin"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start_index": 85,
            "end_index": 91,
            "text": "Denver",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "flight_search.destination1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "index": 1,
        "speaker": "ASSISTANT",
        "text": "Hello, how can I help you?"
      },
      {
        "index": 2,
        "speaker": "ASSISTANT",
        "text": "San Francisco to Denver, got it.",
        "segments": [
          {
            "start_index": 0,
            "end_index": 13,
            "text": "San Francisco",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "flight_search.origin"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start_index": 17,
            "end_index": 23,
            "text": "Denver",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "flight_search.destination1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Code:**

```py
import json
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate

f = open('test.json')

data = json.load(f)
target = "ja"
translate_client = translate.Client()

for conv in data:
    for utt in conv["utterances"]:
        utt["text"] = translate_client.translate(utt["text"], target_language=target)["translatedText"]
        if "segments" in utt:
            for seg in utt["segments"]:
                seg["text"] = translate_client.translate(seg["text"], target_language=target)["translatedText"]

#print(data) # prints a dictionary

json_object = json.dumps(data, indent=2,ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
print(json_object.decode()) # prints a json string
```

**Output:**

```json
[
  {
    "conversation_id": "dlg-00100680-00e0-40fe-8321-6d81b21bfc4f",
    "instruction_id": "flight-12",
    "utterances": [
      {
        "index": 0,
        "speaker": "USER",
        "text": "こんにちは。サンフランシスコからデンバーまでの民間航空会社の往復便を探したいのですが。",
        "segments": [
          {
            "start_index": 26,
            "end_index": 36,
            "text": "往復",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "flight_search.type"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start_index": 68,
            "end_index": 81,
            "text": "サンフランシスコ",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "flight_search.origin"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start_index": 85,
            "end_index": 91,
            "text": "デンバー",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "flight_search.destination1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {        "index": 1,
        "speaker": "ASSISTANT",
        "text": "こんにちは、どうすればいいですか？"
      },
      {
        "index": 2,
        "speaker": "ASSISTANT",
        "text": "サンフランシスコからデンバーへ、了解。",
        "segments": [
          {
            "start_index": 0,
            "end_index": 13,
            "text": "サンフランシスコ",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "flight_search.origin"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start_index": 17,
            "end_index": 23,
            "text": "デンバー",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "flight_search.destination1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It's showing me "Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7fa3fd454290>)". errorPhoto: https://ibb.co/5451qWp

Comment: @RasheeqIshmam it seems that your error is that you are not being authenticated properly. You might want to try and fix the authentication part first.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed the authentication error and then it worked perfectly as wanted. :)